# Aws MySQL serverless v2 will not scale down to 0.5 ACU even though 0 connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora

My Aurora MySQL serverless v2 doesn't have any connections, but automatically keeps 2 ACUs for a few hours, then goes back down to the lowest 0.5, and after a few hours, it keeps 2 ACUs again. Even though there is no connection, this situation keeps repeating. Does anyone know solution? Please explain it clearly.

Someone say that we need to turn off the AI monitoring on the DB. But I couldn't find AI monitoring anywhere.

Comment: Have you figured out what it was? I see the same problem but AI/PI monitoring is off.

Answer (score 0):

It's Performance Insights that you need to turn off.

Comment: Where and How to turn off Performance Insights ?
Please explain it clearly. @Antoine

Comment: Modify the RDS instance and look for Performance Insights. Uncheck the box.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with posgres serverless v2 never dropping below 2vcpus even though my minimum was 0.5.   I'm not sure if this was the problem in OPs case, but for anyone else finding this please try these things:

- disable performance insights as Antoine says
- look under maintenance and backups for an pending upgrades.  You may need to apply these upgrades to get your database to scale down
- upgrade your engine version, if possible

In my case I already had performance insights disabled, so I did 2 & 3, and then my vcpus finally dropped to 0.5.